# Get DISTINCT show.name and COUNT of associated seasons

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement that outputs a table with the two columns show name and number of seasons. The show column must contain no duplocates and the number of seasons column counts the number of seasons associated with the show entity.

**Here are my two tables**

**Shows Table**

id  | name

**Seasons Table**

id | show_id | season_number

**Here's what I've tried so far**

```
SELECT DISTINCT shows.name
FROM shows
INNER JOIN seasons on show.id = seasons.show_id;
```

The above code works for grabbing distinct names but whenever I try adding COUNT(season.id) it breaks.
 
Any suggestions?  
Thanks!

Comment: You should use GROUP BY; then you can use COUNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` to aggregate multiple rows with the same name into a group.  With `count(distinct id)` you calculate the number of distinct values of the id column in that group.

```
SELECT  name
,       COUNT(DISTINCT seasons.id)
FROM    shows
JOIN    seasons
ON      shows.show_id = seasons.show_id
GROUP BY
        name
```

By the way, I'd expect a season to have a one to many relation to show, not the other way around.

Comment: doesn't shows.id = seasons.show_id infer that the season has a one-to-many relationship with the show?

Comment: That would be the other way around, so you'd need only one row per season, and one row per show.  The `on` clause would look like `show.season_id = season.id`

Comment: ah you're right I had that backwards. But since each show will have multiple seasons I want the seasons to be in a many-to-one relationship. Your solution worked Thanks!

Comment: Ah I see now, I thought a show was an episode, but it's show -> series -> episode :)